# Adjust form height according to total row count in datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

```
void PopulateApplications()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
        {
            var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
            ima = icon.ToBitmap();
            ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
            ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
            String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima, p.ProcessName, status);
        }
    }
    int rc = dataGridView1.Rows.Count * ROW_SIZE;
}
```

In this case after the first itertion there are 10 rows added i know already that each row height is 22.
So rc = 220.

Now in the beginning in the designer the form1 size is: 648, 332 
I checked manualy before and 648, 332 is fit for the rows height but let's say i change the form1 size in the designer and start with: 648, 200 and there are 5 rows or 20 rows. So i want to calculate all the rows height and set the form1 size to fit for all the rows.

Cause each user when running the program have other number of processes running at time. So not for everyone 648, 332 is a good size of form1.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem.

```
void PopulateApplications()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
        {
            var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
            ima = icon.ToBitmap();
            ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
            ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
            String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima, p.ProcessName, status);
        }
    }

    int totalRowSize = dataGridView1.Rows.Count * 22;
    int formHeight = this.Size.Height;

    if (totalRowSize > formHeight-30)
        this.Height = totalRowSize + 30;
}
```